# How to do get multiple field collection value in a drop-down of same node in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have a content type and I have separated fields with field group (horizontally tab). there is 2 field collection. I want to get the field value from one field collection and set as for select list in the second field collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to do the same: This is just an example please use machine name of content type and field collection carefully.

```
$nid = 1234; //Dummy Value

//loading node based on nid
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);  

//Here I used field_collection_first_field as machine name of the field collection name on your content type
if(!($node->get('field_collection_first_field')->isEmpty())){

    //Field collection 1
    $fcID1 = $node->get('field_collection_first_field')->getValue()[0]['value'];

    if(!empty($fcID1)){
        $fc1 = \Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem::load($fcID);
        $fcFieldValue = $fc1->get('field_comments')->getValue()[0]['value'];
    }
}

if(isset($fcFieldValue)){

    if(!($node->get('field_collection_second_field')->isEmpty())){

        //Field collection 2
        $fcID1 = $node->get('field_collection_second_field')->getValue()[0]['value'];

        if(!empty($fcID1)){
            $fc2 = \Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem::load($fcID);

            $fc->set('field_comments',$fcFieldValue);

            if(!($fc->save())){
                echo 'success'; //Work Done
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you face any other problem please do let me know